# how to call different methods on two UITextfields in iphone application

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have an iphone application in which i have two text fields and i have four methods to call on those textfields but problem is that when i change the values of textfield one in second method same value is shown in the first methods while loading.

```
    -(void)textFieldTextDidChangeOneF:(UITextField*)tf{

        NSLog(@"Testing Successful Fatal One");

        appDelegate.p_Fatal_Yes_NV_InModel  = [[textFieldOne text] floatValue];
        appDelegate.p_Fatal_No_NV_InModel=100-appDelegate.p_Fatal_Yes_NV_InModel;

        textFieldTwo.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.p_Fatal_No_NV_InModel];

        NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];
        NSString*string=textFieldOne.text;
        if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {
            UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Only a number can be entered into this input field " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            textFieldOne.text=@"";
        }

        NSLog(@"Fata Data %.2f",appDelegate.p_Fatal_Yes_NV_InModel);
    }
```

I am changing value in this method but also values changes I think problem may calling different methods on same textfield.

here is the code link for complete code

I have two textfields but i am calling four methods on them

http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=4011

Comment: you mean you want to call two different method on same textfield for same event(eg. [txt addTarget:self action:@selector(mymethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; [txt addTarget:self action:@selector(mymethod1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged])
this is what you want to do?

Comment: yes i am calling like this as given in my code but there come conflict in variable values

Answer (score 2):

Try Using `tag` property on `UITextField`.

First assign tags to your TextFields programmatically or in xib if you have.
Example

```
[txtFieldOne setTag:100];
[txtFieldTwo setTag:101];
```

Then differentiate action on your text field using tag like

```
-(void)textFieldTextDidChangeOneF:(UITextField*)tf
{
    switch (tf.tag) {
        case 100:
            NSLog(@"action on text field one"); 
        break;

        case 101:
            NSLog(@"action on text field two");
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }
}
```